# Error when installing node-bluetooth package?

Tags: node.js, npm, bluetooth

I am receiving an error while installing node-bluetooth module. I have already installed node-gyp but still receiving the error:

```
BluetoothSerialPortServer.vcxproj -> C:\Users\Marios H\WebstormProjects\demo3\server\node_modules\node-bluetooth\build\Release\\BluetoothSerialPortServer.node
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:194:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:275:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18363
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "configure" "build"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Marios H\WebstormProjects\demo3\server\node_modules\node-bluetooth
gyp ERR! node -v v12.18.2
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN server@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN server@1.0.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-bluetooth@1.2.6 install: `node-gyp configure build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-bluetooth@1.2.6 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Marios H\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-07-21T10_04_19_956Z-debug.log
```

Also i have installed Visual Studio Build Tools 2017